# Experimental Probability formula

Tags: probability

I realize experimental probability is found from $\frac{the\;number\;of\;times\;event\;occurs}{total\;number\;of\;trials}$.

However, somewhere in the back of my mind, I have a formula that adds 1 to both the numerator and denominator, and I can't seem to find any way to figure out what distinguishes these two formulas. Is this a valid formula, and when would it be used as opposed to the above? Where might this memory be coming from?

$\frac{the\;number\;of\;times\;event\;occurs\;+1}{total\;number\;of\;trials\;+1}$

Comment: The second formula makes no sense for me.

Comment: It would make more sense to add $2$ to the denominator when adding $1$ to the numerator (consider the probability of the complementary event).  And that calculation would give the posterior expectation if the prior distribution is uniform.  The advantage of the additions is that you are not stuck on an extreme point estimate until you see both at least one success and at least one failure (if you toss a coin once and see one head, does it make sense to say your estimate of the probability of heads is $100\%$?).  It also enables an estimate before there have been any trials

Comment: For more on @Henry's suggestion, see [rule of succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession).

Comment: Ah, this is very helpful. I teach high school students, and many of them came in with some idea of needing to add one to the frequency of an event, and it sounded vaguely familiar to me as well. Is this something commonly taught at the high school level?

Answer (score 0):

Experimental probability is defined as the ratio of the number of times an event occurs to the total number of trials or times the activity is performed, thus the first formula/ratio you have stated is correct. What distinguishes these two formulas is the $+1$ in the second one gives the incorrect answer for the experimental probability, for example $\frac{3}{5} \neq \frac{4}{6}$. Thus the second formula is not valid. Unfortunately, I'm not really sure where your memory of this has come from, perhaps some other formula entirely?